# From a.e. convergence to pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about a.e. convergence.

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence of continous functions on $K$. We assume that $f_n(x) \to 0$ a.e. $x \in K$

**Question**

Can we show that $f_{n}(x)\to 0$ **for every** $x \in K$ ?

**My idea**

Set
\begin{align*}
A&=\left\{ x \in K : \lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}(x) \neq 0 \right\} , \\
B&=\left\{ x \in K : \lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}(x)= 0 \right\}.
\end{align*}

If $A \neq \emptyset$, there exists $y \in K$, $\epsilon_{0}>0$ and subsequence $\{n_{k}\}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\text{ for every }k \ge 1, |f_{n_{k}}(y)| \ge \epsilon_0 .
\end{align*}
Since $B$ is a dense subset of $K$, we can find $x_k \in A$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\text{ for every }k \ge 1, |f_{n_{k}}(y)-f_{n_{k}}(x_k)| < \epsilon_0/2.
\end{align*}

Accordingly, for all $k \ge 1$, 
\begin{align*}
|f_{n_k}(y)| <|f_{n_{k}}(x_k)|+\epsilon_0/2
\end{align*}
But for large $k$ enough, say $K$, $|f_{n_K}(x_K)|<\epsilon_0/2$ holds because $x_K \in B$. Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
|f_{n_K}(y)|<|f_{n_K}(x_K)|+\epsilon_0/2<\epsilon_0
\end{align*}
This is contradiction.

Is this correct?

Comment: $B$ may not be dense. For instance $K=[0,1]\cup \{1+1/n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $B=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $d=1$, $K=[0,1]$ and $f_n(x)=x^n$.

Then your initial conditions are met:

> $f_n(x)\to 0$ for all $x$ in $[0,1)$, which means
>   $$f_n(x)\to 0 \text{ a.e.}$$
>   is true

However, it is *not* true that $\forall x: f_n(x)\to 0$, because, $f_n(1)=1$ for every $n$.

---

Furthermore, you can extend the counterexample to any dimension, by defining

$$f(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_d) = x_1^n$$

and taking $K=[0,1]^d$:

- Clearly, $f_n(x)\to 0$ for almost all $x\in K$. The set on which this is not true is $A=\{(1,x_2,\dots, x_d)| x_i\in[0,1]\}$ which has measure $0$ (it is a $d-1$-dimensional set!)
- $\forall x\in A\forall n\in\mathbb N: f_n(x)=1$.

---

OK, so clearly your proof must be wrong, but where did you go wrong? Well, for one thing, you claim that $B$ is dense, which may not be the case.

But in my example, $B$ is dense, but still this is not enough to conclude that $f_n(x)\to 0$ everywhere. So you must have made another error.

Your error is in saying

> But for large $k$ enough, say $K$, $|f_{n_K}(x_K)|<\epsilon_0/2$ holds because $x_K \in B$

This is **not true**, because as you move $K$, you are changing both $f_{n_K}$ *as well as* $x_K$. There exists a sequence $x_k$ such that:

- For all $k$, $x_k\in B$
- For all $k$ $f_k(x_k) > \frac12$

Which proves that your claim is wrong.

---

Your claim would be correct if you had a **fixed** value of $x\in B$, and you would the claim

> There exists some $K$ such that $|f_K(x)|<\epsilon$.

But what you claimed was a stronger (and false) claim.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Certainly, $B$ is not dense.

Comment: @sharpe Actually, in my counterexample, $B$ **IS DENSE**, but that's not enough. You made another error. I will edit my answer to explain.

Comment: @sharpe your $|f_{n_k}(x_{n_k})|<\epsilon$ is wrong. The convergence is not necessarily uniform. To use the convergence on $B$, you have to *fix* a certain point, say $x_{n_k}$ for a *fixed* $k$.

Comment: @sharpe See the bottom part of my answer for your second mistake.

Comment: OK. I understood. By the way, there exists suffiecient condition that a.e. convergence implies pointwise convergence ?

Comment: @sharpe I don't know of any "nice" condition. You would have to demand something like uniform convergence, but that's a very strong condition...

Comment: @5xum You mean If $f_{n}(x) \to 0$ uniformly a.e. implies $f_{n}(x) \to 0$ for all x ?

Comment: @sharpe No, I mean if $f_n\to 0$ uniformly, then $f_n(x)\to 0$ for all $x$. But as I said, that's not really useful.